# MySQL select and update in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'd would like to have an MySQL command
*`UPDATE.....SELECT`* 
to update my `Previous_Change_Date`
as the below table.

could anyone please help?

```
+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Product_Number | Change_Date | Previous_Change_Date |
+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
|       30000319 |  1178581980 |           1178581860 |
|       30000319 |  1178581860 |           1170916740 |
|       30000319 |  1170916740 |           1138779000 |
|       30000319 |  1138779000 |                 NULL |
|       30000327 |  1178581860 |           1138779000 |
|       30000327 |  1138779000 |                 NULL |
|       30000348 |  1170916740 |           1162451400 |
|       30000348 |  1162451400 |                 NULL |
|       30000443 |  1195713360 |           1191287160 |
|       30000443 |  1191287160 |           1184720940 |
|       30000443 |  1184720940 |           1176421080 |
|       30000443 |  1176421080 |           1173766980 |
|       30000443 |  1173766980 |           1173050460 |
|       30000443 |  1173050460 |           1170816780 |
|       30000443 |  1170816780 |           1170496980 |
|       30000443 |  1170496980 |           1166078340 |
|       30000443 |  1166078340 |                 NULL |
+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: you want to set Previous_Change_Date to be same as Change_Date??

Comment: Do you have an auto increment field in that table?

Comment: @Fawas, I cant understand your problem, i think if you want to select that table and update the date(Previous_Change_Date) query.

Comment: @Fawas, if you using the primary key in that table...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a mysql [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html). This way you could have the luxury of variables and for loops. This would be a lot easier to implement and maintain.

You could use [this post](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843) as an introductive tutorial.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) on insert, here's a fiddle with trigger

[trigger fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91e04/1)

but if you don't want here's what you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Product_Number, Change_Date, Previous_Change_Date) 
VALUES (product_num_value, change_date_value, 
(SELECT date FROM (SELECT MAX(Change_Date) AS date FROM table_name 
WHERE Product_Number='product_num_value') as temp_table));
```

You have to change `table_name` to your actual table_name and change the values `product_num_value` and `change_date_value`

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cb03/1)